# SIGABRT error when using NSTimer, Swift 2 Xcode 7

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7, nstimer, sigabrt

I have a function that flashes a button. The function is inside a `for i loop`, which is in the `viewDidLoad` function. I also have an `NSTimer` that calls the function repeatedly flashing a different button each time. However I am getting a `SIGABRT error` when I run this. If you are going to ask, I have made sure that the connections with my buttons are solid, no cut off connections.

```
var computerChoices = [Int](count: 11, repeatedValue: 0)
var randomIndex = 0
var pcChoice = 0
var lit = [b0o,b1o,b2o,b3o,b4o,b5o,b6o,b7o,b8o]
var litIndex = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for i in 1...10{

        print(randomIndex)
        print(computerChoices)

        var buttonChoice = lit[randomIndex]

        randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(lit.count)))
        computerChoices[i] = randomIndex

        print("yoyoyo")

        func flashingButtons(){
            var one = computerChoices[pcChoice]
            lit[one].setImage(UIImage(named: "redb.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            pcChoice += 1

        }
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("flashingButtons"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: At what line do you get the error, possible at `computerChoices[i] = randomIndex`? Most likely you're trying to access an index of a collection type, where the corresponding member does not exist. ("index out of bounds")

Comment: how do i tell the timer to stop at a specific time?

Comment: Is this code in the scope of a view controller? (Just making sure)

Comment: Also, I can't see where you've define the `timer` property (only where you mutate it)

Comment: yes, i tried stopping the timer when pcChoice == i but still had the same error

Comment: Then probably what Saketram said before (map "flashingButtons" )

Comment: You might want to adjust your `randomIndex` to subtract 1 from `lit.count` so you don't get an out of bounds error.  You could get a randomIndex value of 10 (based on the count), but the last index of a 10-item array is 9 b/c indexes start at 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put out the `flashingButtons` function out of the viewDidLoad. The timer find the function and couldn't find it if it is embedded.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for i in 1...10{

        print(randomIndex)
        print(computerChoices)

        var buttonChoice = lit[randomIndex]

        randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(lit.count)))
        computerChoices[i] = randomIndex

        print("yoyoyo")

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("flashingButtons"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}

func flashingButtons(){
    var one = computerChoices[pcChoice]
    lit[one].setImage(UIImage(named: "redb.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    pcChoice += 1

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put `flashingButtons()` out side `viewDidLoad`. And in it you make sure that `out of range` don't happen because `pcChoice` increase over time.

```
 func flashingButtons(){
    var one = computerChoices[pcChoice]
    lit[one].setImage(UIImage(named: "redb.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    if pcChoice >= 10 {
        pcChoice = 0
        return
    }
    pcChoice += 1

}
```